# Align buttons to the center of a window with TK python

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a small python script that uses TK to build a user interface.
I'm not able to align two buttons, `"Start"` and `"Cancel"`,  to the center of my window. Now they are at the bottom left, but I would like to place them close together in the center (at the bottom). Here's my code:

```
import sys, os
import tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("My Program")
root.geometry("450x250+500+200")

def star_program():
   print "start"

def sel():
   selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
   label.config(text = selection)

def open_file_1():
    os.system("gedit /home/user/Desktop/1.txt")

def open_file_2():
    os.system("gedit /home/user/Desktop/2.txt")

tk.Label(root, 
     text="""Hello World""",
     justify = tk.LEFT,
     bd = 12, padx = 20, font = 'Arial 11 bold').pack()

var = IntVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Choise (1)", variable=var, value=1)
R1.pack( anchor = W )

R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Choise (2)", variable=var, value=2)
R2.pack( anchor = W )

R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Choise (3)", variable=var, value=3)
R3.pack( anchor = W )


B = tk.Button(root, text ="Open File 1", font = 'Arial 10 bold', command = open_file_2)
B.pack( anchor = W )

C = tk.Button(root, text ="Open File 2", font = 'Arial 10 bold', command = open_file_1)
C.pack( anchor = W )

label = Label(root)
label.pack()

start_button = Button(root, 
               text="Start",
               command=star_program)
cancel_button = Button(root,
               text="Cancel",
               command=quit)

start_button.pack(side = LEFT)
cancel_button.pack(side = LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried to use different options inside pack, like x & y or side = bottom, but nothing.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: I have no idea how you can both import `tkinter` and `Tkinter` in the same file and use it to prove even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be to put them in a frame and put `pack` that frame with `side` option set to `'bottom'`. Replace:

```
start_button = Button(root, 
               text="Start",
               command=star_program)
cancel_button = Button(root,
               text="Cancel",
               command=quit)

start_button.pack(side = LEFT)
cancel_button.pack(side = LEFT)
```

with:

```
start_cancel = tk.Frame(root)
start_cancel.pack(side='bottom')

start_button = tk.Button(start_cancel, 
               text="Start",
               command=star_program)
cancel_button = tk.Button(start_cancel,
               text="Cancel",
               command=quit)

start_button.pack(side = 'left')
cancel_button.pack(side = 'left')
```

---

Note that you're using attributes from `from Tkinter import *` and `import tkinter as tk` seemingly at random, that makes your code pretty inconsistent to read.